# Open Bokeh application in different browser tab?

Tags: bokeh

I am running a bokeh application with different tabs. I love to open same application in different browsers. So I can use different application tabs in different monitors. For now, I can only connect one browser at a time. I am using

```
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab0,tab1])
curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

for opening the application. And runs with

```
bokeh serve myapp.py
```

How can I use bokeh client or anything?? Any working example??

Open Bokeh application in different browser tab?

Comment: Have you tried opening the bokeh application in multiple browsers? You can just copy and paste the URL and open it in as many browser tabs as you'd like.

Comment: With command http://localhost:5006/gui?bokeh-session-id=14831 I can open in multiple browsers. But If I change the tabs in my application it also changes the tabs in the browser. I want application tabs to be static.

Comment: What about opening ` localhost:5006/gui` instead?

Comment: It shows some error. If I use bokeh serve --num-procs. I can open another browser. But they will be independent. I cannot stream data.

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh works the following way: The application is a blueprint to create a document. There are two documents: one on the python side (on the server) and one on the javascript side (on the client in the browser). Bokeh automatically synchronizes both documents. This means if you open a tab on the client it will also be in the opened state on the server.

When you now open a specific python document twice (e.g. open twice  `localhost:5006/gui?bokeh-session-id=14831`) you get one python document and two js documents and all are synchronized. That means if you open a tab it gets opened in all documents, so all js documents.

If you want two js documents with different state, you need to have two python documents (e.g. by opening `localhost:5006/gui`). Now these two python documents are not synchronized anymore, which enables you to have two different tabs open

Now you want to have multiple js documents with different state (you want different tabs active). These cannot be synchronized to the same python document, because otherwise opening a tab in js document 1 would open the tab in js document 2. So you need two different python documents, but now these two python documents are not synchronized anymore.

From your comments I think you want to synchronize part of your documents, but not everything. As far as I know bokeh has no support for this.

One hack you could try is to disable event propagation for the tabs. Another way would be to synchronize the data you care about yourself.

Comment: Can I run two bokeh application with shared data source among them?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understood the limitation.

Comment: I don't think that bokeh supports that out of the box, you would probably need to dive deep into bokeh. How do you modify your data sources? Theoretically all you need to do is to distribute the modifications to all documents, practically that might be more challanging.

Answer (score 0):

My intended purpose was to see different tabs in different browsers(in different monitors). It was quite difficult to do with bokeh alone. I can open two application at different browsers but it will be a mirror of other application (If I choose tabs the same is seen in the other) or it will completely independent.

To synchronise two application I used **SAMP** protocol in **astropy**. I created one application as Server and the other as the client. The server sends the variables to the client through the **SAMP** protocol. Now changes in the server are received in the client but I can do independent things with the client. Like I can switch to any tab as I like. Works pretty well for my purpose.

Please see

https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/samp/example_table_image.html